# Derivate of log of sum of elements of a vector with respect to the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$x$ is of shape $1 \times d$
$W$ is of shape $d \times k$

$f(W) = log(\sum e^{xW})$

Here the summation is over the $k$ elements after applying the exponent to the vector product $xW$

I have to find the derivative of $f(W)$ with respect to $W$.

Here's what I've done:

Let's assume a vector $\bf{1}$ of shape $k \times 1$ whose each element is 1. Thus $f(W) = log(e^{xW}\bf{1})$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W}f(W) = \frac{\partial}{\partial W}log(e^{xW}\bf{1})$$
Using the chain rule:
$$=x^T e^{xW} \mathbf{1} \frac{1}{e^{xW}\mathbf{1}}$$
$$=x^T$$

Is that correct?
Shouldn't the shape of the derivative be same as the quantity with respect to which it was differentiated i.e. $W$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's use column vectors rather than row vectors, i.e. wherever you've used $x$ I'll use $x^T$.

Next, define some new variables to reduce the visual clutter.
$$\eqalign{
y,p,{\tt 1} &\in{\mathbb R}^{k\times 1} \\
y &= W^Tx &\implies dy = dW^Tx \\
p &= \exp(y) &\implies dp = p\odot dy \\
\phi &= {\tt 1}:p &\implies d\phi = {\tt 1}:dp \\
\lambda &= \phi^{-1} \\
}$$
where ${\tt 1}$ is a vector of all ones, the exponential function is applied elementwise, $(\odot)$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product, and $(:)$ is the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\;A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$.

Write the function in terms of the new variables. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log(\phi) \\
df
 &= d\log(\phi) \\
 &= \lambda\,d\phi \\
 &= \lambda\,{\tt 1}:dp \\
 &= \lambda\,{\tt 1}:p\odot dy \\
 &= \lambda\,p:dy \\
 &= \lambda\,p:dW^Tx \\
 &= \lambda\,p^T:x^TdW \\
 &= \lambda\,xp^T:dW \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} &= \lambda\,xp^T \;\in\,{\mathbb R}^{d\times k} \\
\\
}$$
So, as you suspected, the gradient has the *same shape* as $W$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I've a doubt. In the first line ,$y = W^Tx \implies dy = dW^Tx$ will imply that $\frac{dy}{dW^T} = x$. Shouldn't the derivative of $y$ wrt $W^T$ should of the same dimension as $W^T$ ?

Comment: No, the **gradient** of a vector ($y$) wrt a matrix ($W^T$) is a **not** a vector but a _3rd order tensor_. There is no way to represent such a quantity within matrix notation. That is why the differential approach is useful, because the **differential** of a {scalar, vector, matrix} is simply another {scalar, vector, matrix}.